# Localization in a custom Laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization, laravel-package

My service provider of my custom package has the following lines in the `boot()` method:

```php
$this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/lang', 'name');
$this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../resources/lang' => resource_path('lang/vendor/name'),
        ], 'lang');
```

I ran the `php artisan vendor:publish` command and the `packages/vendorname/packagename/resources/lang/de.json` file was successfully copied to the project.

The translation is not working. I tried copying to the `/lang/vendor/name/` folder as well.

When I move my `de.json` file manually to `/lang` then the translation is working. To there is no issue with the file itself.

I tried to clear all caches already.

Comment: I believe, if you couple translations from a custom package, you need to use the translation_key with `packageName::file.key` format. In your example, you show you coupled translations to the package name `name`. Have you tried setting a custom value here and then loading the translation with that prefix?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages#translations

Comment: Yeah, that's it! I just read the entire Localization documentation but forget to check the package documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why, But, it seems that Laravel just loads only the JSON translation files of the main project and the first package in the Vendor folder.

My solution is:

1. for loading the ***JSON*** translation files from your package, you have to
   use ***loadJsonTranslationsFrom*** in your package's service provider:

   ```
   class CustomeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       /**
        * Bootstrap the package services.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function boot()
       {
           $this->loadJsonTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/lang');
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your ***JSON*** file ***you can use your package name as a prefix for every key***. for example, if your package name is ***MyPackage***, your ***en.json*** file
   looks like:

   ```
   {
     "MyPackage::email": "Email",
     "MyPackage::username": "Username",
     ...
   }
   ```
3. You can use some helper functions of Laravel to load your translation keys:

   ```
   trans('MyPackage::email'); // returns "Email"
   OR
   __('MyPackage::username'); // returns "Username"
   ```

You can follow the links below for more information:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/loadjsontranslationsfrom-does-not-load-all-json-translation-files

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17923

[Laravel 5 loadJsonTranslationsFrom method does not load all JSON translation files from packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510082/laravel-5-loadjsontranslationsfrom-method-does-not-load-all-json-translation-fil)

https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/pull/412

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20599